# What is the difference between scipy.ndimage.imread and matplotlib.pyplot.imread?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, keras

`scipy.ndimage.imread` has just been deprecated in scipy, so I switched my code directly to use pyplot - but the result was not the same. I am importing images for a learning algorithm built in keras - I thought it would be a 1to1 change - but it isn't - I was training fine, after the switch my system doesn't train. Is there a python guru out there that can explain what the difference is?

Scipy returns:

> img_array : ndarray
>       The different colour bands/channels are stored in the third dimension, such that a grey-image is MxN, an RGB-image MxNx3 and an
>   RGBA-image MxNx4.
>   [scipy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.imread.html)

Matplotlib returns:

> Return value is a numpy.array. For grayscale images, the return array
>   is MxN. For RGB images, the return value is MxNx3. For RGBA images the
>   return value is MxNx4.
>   [matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imread.html)

MWE:

```py
from scipy import ndimage
import_image = (ndimage.imread("img.png").astype(float) - 
                                          255.0 / 2) / 255.0
print import_image[0]

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import_image = (plt.imread("img.png").astype(float) - 
                                          255.0 / 2) / 255.0

print import_image[0]
```

Comment: I think one main difference concerns png images. `plt.imread` has its own function to read pngs while `scipy.ndimage.imread` uses PIL. For all other file formats both functions should use PIL, so I would not expect a difference. Concerning your actual problem, you could of course provide us with a test case, such that people are able to reproduce the behaviour.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest please see updated with MWE - I use a greyscale image.

Comment: Where is the error / problem you observe? What should i take from your example? You can also use the lib recommended as alternative. But it's probably less about decoding and more about array-type decisions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here would be a true mcve:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage

im = np.random.rand(20,20)
plt.imsave("img.png",im)

### Scipy
i2 = scipy.ndimage.imread("img.png")
print i2.shape, i2.min(), i2.max(), i2.dtype
# (20L, 20L, 4L) 1 255 uint8

### Matplotlib
i3 = plt.imread("img.png").astype(float)
print i3.shape, i3.min(), i3.max(), i3.dtype
# (20L, 20L, 4L) 0.00392156885937 1.0 float64
```

As can be seen

- `scipy.ndimage.imread` creates a numpy array of `int` type ranging from `0..255` while
- `pyplot.imread` creates a numpy array of float type ranging from `0. .. 1.`.